# strpccmd all of the sudden doesn't work anymore

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

We have a program with the next lines:

```
// Editor voor blob opstarten
@cmdString = 'STRPCO';
callp(e) excCmd(@CmdString :%len(@CmdString));

@cmdString = 'STRPCCMD PCCMD(' + '''' +
             'CMD /C START ' +
             '\\' + %trim(@systeemNaam) +
              %trim(@blob_name) +  ''''  +
              ') PAUSE(*NO)';
excCmd(@CmdString :%len(@CmdString));
```

The value of @cmdString in the bottom line has the value:

STRPCCMD PCCMD('CMD /C START \SYSTEMNAME>/INPUT/PZ/TEMP/<DocumentName.doc') PAUSE(*NO)

This command opens the document in word. But after 9 years and 2 months all of a sudden it gaves this error and when the users click OK the RPG error runs in an error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSnNV.png)

There are few  odd things:

- when I debug the program to avoid that the programs runs in an error and starts the function to open the word document again, it opens fine. And it works fine as long as I not close this specific session
- When I open a new session, which normally gives an error when calling this function, and insert a breakpoint at the second last line and wait there for a few second and hit F12 then the word document opens fine.

Till now I can't find the cause of this error. This someone has an idea?

Debugging and check the authorities on the IBM i and the IFS. The authorities didn't change compared to the situation before the disruption.

Comment: Please include the actual error message being received as English text, not a screen shot in another language.

Comment: Current version of IBM i? Recent changes? PTFs? Recent network changes that correspond with this error?

Comment: Hi Charles,
The system doesn't give an error message. Windows explorer gives an error about authorisation, but that's not what is going on, because when I built in a delay of more than 4 seconds, then the documents opens fine.

Comment: Hi jmarkmurphy,

The latest PTF's were stored in april. The error of not opening the word document appears in august for the first time. So that could not be the problem.

It also can not be a network problem. The document is on the IFS so the process doesn't use the network. The team for workplaces told that there has not been changes on the word applications on the laptops.

Comment: So what was the resolution, only out if interst?